# Leer cadenas linux bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

estoy atascado en un problema de linux bash, se me pide que el programa me pida tres cadenas por teclado y comprobara si el texto introducido es valido y si corresponde lo introducido a nombres de algun directorio, si lo es, se debe listar que dentro de ellos y sino pues indicar que es un error y que no corresponde a un directorio. Bien, interpreto que para conseguir primeramente lo que pide, es que el programa pida por teclado las cadenas, para luego comprobar si corresponde a algún directorio el nombre, pero no consigo hacerlo.

```
    #!/bin/bash
directorio=/root
echo "Pedir tres cadenas por teclado";
read -p "Dime una string:" string1;
read -p "Dime otra string:" string2;
read -p "Dime otra string mas:" string3;
echo "La primera cadena es," $string1;
echo "La segunda cadena es," $string2;
echo "La tercera cadena es," $string3;

if [ $string1 == -d $directorio ]
then;
  echo "La cadena1 es el nombre de un directorio";
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena1 no corresponde al nombre de un directorio."
fi;

if [ $string2 == -d $directorio ] 
then;
  echo "La cadena2 es el nombre de un directorio";
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena2 no corresponde al nombre de un directorio"
fi;

if [ $string3 == -d $directorio ] 
then;
  echo "La cadena3 es el nombre de un directorio";
else
  echo "ERROR: LA cadena3 no corresponde al nombre de un directorio"
fi;
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Proporciona un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así se comprueba que un directorio existe:

```sh
if [ -d "$string1" ];
```

Seguido del *punto y coma*, para moverte entre directorios usa:

```sh
cd "$directorio"
```

Y para listar el contenido:

```sh
ls
```

---

**La diferencia:**

```sh
cd "$directorio"

if [ -d "$string1" ];
then
  echo ""
  echo "La cadena1 es el nombre de un directorio."
  echo "Su contenido ($string1):"

  ls ./"$string1"
else
  echo "ERROR: La cadena1 no corresponde al nombre de un directorio."
fi
```

Comment: perfectísimo, me ha servido muchas gracias y ha solventado mis dudas para, no lograba dar con el objetivo de la comparación.